# Set default date when form is composed from calendar view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Does anyone know how to set the default date when a user double clicks in the notes calendar view?  For example, when you double click on the 18th Feb, I want a field StartDate in my new form to be the 18th Feb.

It is done in the notes mail template, however it uses fairly complex nesting of script libraries and custom objects which has confused me.

I had thought of using environment variables, however this can be a bit messy if a user's client crashes etc, so would prefer another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date just use the CalendarDateTime property of the NotesUIView element in the Regiondoubleclick method.

```
Sub Regiondoubleclick(Source As Notesuiview)
    Print source.calendarDateTime
    Print "did you see it?"
End Sub
```

You can assign the value of source.calendarDateTime to datetime variable or a field, like startdate, in your new document.

Comment: I am not quite sure why I did not look at the notesuiview properties.  Works a treat.  Thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 0):

The RegionDoubleClick code which is what executes when you double click an empty area in a date on a calendar view executes this code `@If(@TextToNumber(@Version) < 174;"";  @Do(@Environment("CSBroadcast";"0"); @Command([Compose];"Appointment")))` which after normal evaluation composes a document using the appointment form. the default value for StartDate on the Appointment form is `@If(StartDate = ""; @If(@IsAvailable(StartDateTime);StartDateTime; @Today); StartDate)` which will set the date to todays date. You can use both of those statements in the same places in your custom application views and form

Comment: I have tried both, however it still uses @Today as the default date.  I would assume this is because 'StartDateTime' does not have a value, and that value has not come across from the doubleclick?

Comment: So you are looking for a way to do this without lotusscript?

Comment: Nope - no not mind.  With or without.  I'm not sure how to get the time selected into the new form when it is created.